# How to import a JSON file from a different folder

Tags: python, json, configuration

So I am working on a project where I have a package for configurations so literally :
inside the package configuration there is another one called defaults and have multiple `.py` files but also 2 JSON files. In a `.py` file in another package I want to read from this the JSON files. How can I import them?

I tried doing it with sys :

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(1,'....')
import the json file
```

and also tried

```
import os
os.chdir('..')
```

in both cases, I entered the location of the files but it did not work and also I don't want it to be limited to my working directory.

Comment: You don't import JSON files like you import python modules. Use the `json` module from the standard library.

Comment: how can i do this? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Read the friendly manual: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html